# Android Web Scraping for Result

Tags: android, html, web-scraping, jsoup, headless-browser

I am trying to write an application in android studio to submit a form in a website html and parse the result html page for result. I am new to this kind of work and i need help. I have worked with Jsoup in the Past but only to the point where i can connect to html and parse stuff. I am new to submitting forms. The Following is form on the website HTML i want to submit along with the Input Tag.

```html
<form role="form" ng-submit="searchForm.$valid &amp;&amp; searchEircode()" name="searchForm" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-minlength">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input placeholder="Enter a full address or Eircode" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-minlength ng-touched" ng-class="{formcontrolRequired:searchForm.$submitted &amp;&amp; !searchForm.$valid || InvalidEircode}" ng-model="searchQuery" name="searchQuery" required="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" typeahead="address.address for address in getAutoCompleteAddresses($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label)" typeahead-focus-first="true" focus="" ng-minlength="3" search-bar="" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead-64-7981"><ul class="dropdown-menu ng-isolate-scope ng-hide" ng-show="isOpen()" ng-style="{top: position.top+'px', left: position.left+'px'}" style="display: block;;display: block;" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" typeahead-popup="" id="typeahead-64-7981" matches="matches" active="activeIdx" select="select(activeIdx)" query="query" position="position">
    <!-- ngRepeat: match in matches track by $index -->
</ul>
          <span class="input-group-btn" ng-class="{current:loading}">
          <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default btn-search-bar" ng-disabled="loading">
            <div id="floatingCirclesG">
              <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_01"> </div>
              <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_02"> </div>
              <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_03"> </div>
              <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_04"> </div>
              <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_05"> </div>
              <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_06"> </div>
              <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_07"> </div>
              <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_08"> </div>
            </div>
          </span> </div>
        <!-- ngIf: searchForm.$submitted -->
        <div class="error-message ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="InvalidEircode">
          
        </div>
      </form>
```

Any way forward would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the action parameter value of the form? Is there an url where we can see this form?

Answer (score 0):

This would have been easier if you provided the url. But anyways it's very simple. Just open your browser's developer tool, go to **Network** tab.

Then submit the form from the browser normally, then check the network tab for the request being sent by the browser. In the **header** tab you will be able to see all form data that has been sent and the server address.

Then you just need to send the exact same thing with Jsoup :)

I've posted a detailed tutorial on submitting forms (logging in) to a website using Jsoup, check it out [here](http://joelmin.blogspot.com.au/2016/04/how-to-login-to-website-using-jsoup-java.html)